# Stopping a script executing?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
$('body.fb-not-liked').on('click', function(){

        $('#like-to-enter-btn').animate({top:'5'}, 200, 'swing');
        $('#like-to-enter-btn').animate({top:'20'}, 200, 'swing');

        return false;

    });

$('.col:not(.disabled)').on('click', function(){
        $('#modal').animate({top:'40'}, 300, 'swing');
        $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    });
```

How can I make it so that when

```
$('body.fb-not-liked')
```

is clicked, the method

```
$('.col:not(.disabled)').on('click', function(){
```

does not fire?

Comment: Can you post your markup as well ?

Comment: @blunderboy: do you really need the markup?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid It is not clear from the code how clicking on body is triggering click on element having class col and not disabled. However, Otherway can be true. Clicking on col may trigger click on body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a class into the `.col` (example: "no-click") (when clicking  `$('body.fb-not-liked')`) and exclude that class from the click in the `.col`:

**example:**

```
$('.col:not(.disabled):not(.no-click)').on('click', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the use of [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and swapping the events around:

```
$('.col:not(.disabled)').on('click', function(){
        $('#modal').animate({top:'40'}, 300, 'swing');
        $('#overlay').fadeIn();
});

$('body.fb-not-liked').on('click', function() {
        $('.col:not(.disabled)').off('click'); // <----- this here
        $('#like-to-enter-btn').animate({top:'5'}, 200, 'swing');
        $('#like-to-enter-btn').animate({top:'20'}, 200, 'swing');
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Use `off` instead of `unbind`

Comment: @Satpal I thought one or the other initially but you're right. Thanks.